# Start Fragment from SherlockFragment inside a SherlockFragmentActivity - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have an Activity (call Home) extends SherlockFragmentActivity, that has 5 Tabs.
Each Tab is a SherlockFragment.

This is layout home.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This is Adapter for Home :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// Declare the number of ViewPager pages
final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {

    // Open FragmentTab1.java
    case 0:
        FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
        return fragmenttab1;

        // Open FragmentTab2.java
    case 1:
        FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
        return fragmenttab2;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
    case 2:
        FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
        return fragmenttab3;

    case 3:
        FragmentTab4 fragmenttab4 = new FragmentTab4();
        return fragmenttab4;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
    case 4:
        FragmentTab5 fragmenttab5 = new FragmentTab5();
        return fragmenttab5;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}
```

}

Each Tab, that extends SherlockFragment, has a ListView.

All I want is when each item of ListView is clicked, a new Fragment is replaced in the same position.

I try with Adapter for ListView but my app's force-lose.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ......................

private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public ListAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    this.mFragmentManager = fm;
}

    ..............

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    ........................

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create new fragment and transaction
            FragmentDetail newFragment = new FragmentDetail();
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // Replace fragmenttab1.xml layout. It's id is R.id.container 
            ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            ft.commit();

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Here is LogCat. ListVideoAdapter in LogCat is ListAdapter above.

[image]

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: the FragmentManager parsed into your ListAdapter, is that a Child FragmentManager from the Fragment, or a normal one from the Activity?  R.id.container looks to be inside the Fragment, so you should be using the child

Comment: The FragmentManager parsed into my ListAdapter, is from android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.
R.id.container, is "id" of fragmenttab1.xml. It's is layout of FragmentTab1.
Can you tell me clearly ? Thank for helping.

Comment: do you use new ListAdapter(getFragmentManager()) or new ListAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) ?

Comment: I use mListView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(activity)); inside onActivityCreated().

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't initialize convertView, and you have nullpointerexception when setOnclickListener

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: This is summary of my ListAdapter. I just show which is important for fragment, but not completely of ListAdapter. Thank for your reply.

Comment: Ok. Show stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: NPE in ListVideoAdapter on line 67

Comment: In Line 67 is :
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Comment: it means, your mFragmentManager is null, check in debbuger by step